# Concatenation of 2 byte arrays in constructor gives strange result

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qt6

```
Qt 6.2.1 MinGW
```

I have 2 arrays, header `FirstArray` and body `SecondArray`. I know that copy-paste, isn't good in programming, so at first, did so :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    const QByteArray FirstArray=QByteArray(std::begin<char>({static_cast<char>(0xA5), 0x5A, static_cast<char>(0xB5), 0x5B}), 4);
    const QByteArray SecondArray=QByteArray(FirstArray+std::begin<char>({0x18, 0x00, 0x01, static_cast<char>(0x9B), 0x03, 0x09, 0x00, 0x19, static_cast<char>(0x91)}), 13);
    qDebug()<< SecondArray.toHex();

    return a.exec(); 
}
```

I expected the result:

```
"a55ab55b1800019b0309001991"
```

But in output I see:

```
"a55ab55b1800adbaababababab"
```

Then I rewrite the second `QByteArray` initialization, and remove plus operation in constructor:

```
const QByteArray SecondArray=QByteArray(std::begin<char>({static_cast<char>(0xA5), 0x5A, static_cast<char>(0xB5), 0x5B, 0x18, 0x00, 0x01, static_cast<char>(0x9B), 0x03, 0x09, 0x00, 0x19, static_cast<char>(0x91)}), 13);
```

I get:

```
"a55ab55b1800019b0309001991"
```

Why does it's happed in the first case? How to write correctly?

Comment: you already know how to get correct output, no?

Comment: The addition operator expects the right-hand operand to be a null-terminated string. (How did you expect it to determine how many elements there are?) You are probably suffering from undefined behaviour.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes I can copy the header to all my arrays, but I want to understand why the first variant works not correctly.  It will help me to edit the header in future

Comment: @molbdnilo okay, and how I can write a correct initialization in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you are calling

```
const QByteArray operator+(const QByteArray &a1, const char *a2)
```

Which, per its [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-2b-1):

> Returns a byte array that is the result of concatenating byte array a1 and string a2.

It excepts `a2` to point to a null-terminated string.

You can rearrange the concatenation to

```
FirstArray + QByteArray(std::begin<char>({0x18, ......
```

To call the other overload which does not rely on null-termination of a c-string.